# Using iconv with WCHAR_T on Linux

Tags: c, linux, character-encoding, wchar-t

I  have the following code on Linux:-

```
rc = iconv_open("WCHAR_T", SourceCode);
```

prior to using iconv to convert the data into a wide character string (`wchar_t`).

I am trying to understand what it achieves in order to port it to a platform where the option on parameter 1, `"WCHAR_T"`, does not exist.

This leads to sub-questions such as:

- Is there a single representation of `wchar_t` on Linux?
- What codepage does this use? I imagine maybe UTF-32
- Does it rely on any locale settings to achieve this?

I'm hoping for an answer that says something like: "The code you show is shorthand for doing the following 2 things instead...." and then I might be able to do those two steps instead of the shorthand on the platform where `"WCHAR_T"` option on `iconv_open` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the (non-standard) `WCHAR_T` encoding exists is to make it easy to cast a pointer to `wchar_t` into a pointer to `char` and use it with `iconv`.  The format understood by that encoding is whatever the system's native `wchar_t` is.

If you're asking about glibc and not other libc implementations, then on Linux `wchar_t` is a 32-bit type in the system's native endianness, and represents Unicode codepoints.  This is not the same as `UTF-32`, since `UTF-32` normally has a byte-order mark (BOM) and when it does not, is big endian.  `WCHAR_T` is always native endian.

Note that some systems use different semantics for `wchar_t`.  Windows always uses a 16-bit type using a little-endian UTF-16.  If you used the GNU libiconv on that platform, the `WCHAR_T` encoding would be different than if you ran it on Linux.

Locale settings do not affect `wchar_t` because the size of `wchar_t` must be known at compile time, and therefore cannot practically vary based on locale.

If this piece of code is indeed casting a pointer to `wchar_t` and using that in its call to `iconv`, then you need to adjust the code to use one of the encodings `UTF-16LE`, `UTF-16BE`, `UTF-32LE`, or `UTF-32BE`, depending on `sizeof(wchar_t)` and the platform's endianness.  Those encodings do not require (nor allow) a BOM, and assuming you're not using a PDP-11, one of them will be correct for your platform.

If you're getting the data from some other source, then you need to figure out what that is, and use the appropriate encoding from the list above for it.  You should also probably send a patch upstream and ask the maintainer to use a different, more correct encoding for handling their data format.

Comment: When I asked about locale, I wasn't meaning the size of `wchar_t` I was wondering about the codepage used for `wchar_t`. When you say "whatever the system's native `wchar_t`- how do you discover that?

Comment: @MoragHughson Although not an answer to your question, the following wiki is a good reference that describes wchar_t https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character

Comment: `wchar_t` is specified by the C standard.  The values have to be capable of supporting any Unicode codepoint, so as a practical matter, they will be either UCS-4, UTF-16LE, or UTF-16BE.  On Linux, it's UCS-4.  Codepages are a legacy Windows phenomenon, and Unix tends to eschew them in favor of using Unicode.

Comment: On the platform I am porting to, there is no single codepage defined for `wchar_t`, it is, I am told, locale dependant. I am building a 64bit application, so `wchar_t` is 4 bytes on my platform in that situation. It has been suggested that I use `mbtowc`, but this function does not allow me to provide the codepage of the source. Perhaps I should simplify my question. I need to go from a known codepage to `wchar_t` when `iconv_open` doesn't not have the `"WCHAR_T"` encoding.

Comment: @bk2204 the C standard definition is more general: "wchar_t is an integer type whose range of values can represent distinct codes for all members of the largest extended character set specified among the supported locales"

Comment: I'm aware of the requirements on `wchar_t` by the C standard.  Practically, it must somehow be capable of supporting any Unicode codepoint unless you don't wish to use Unicode.  I don't know why your platform is configured in this way, bizarre as it is, but on Linux `wchar_t` is UCS-4 and is not locale dependent.  You should consult your platform's documentation for more assistance.